# laravel nova add the word below calculate in metric

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

in laravel nova, I want to add a description below my calculated result, but I'm not sure where to add it
[image]

this is my simple code in function calculate

```
    public function calculate(Request $request)
{
    return $this->count($request, User::class, 'stripe_plan');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*You have two methods to proceed.*

---

The first is to use the "help" function present in the Laravel Nova Metrics, but this will insert a tooltip. You can enter text or pass a view.
Example:

> File: NovaServiceProvider.php

```
 protected function cards()
 {
    return [
       (new YourMetric())
        ->help('This is your help text.')
        // OR
        ->help(view('nova.metrics.your-metric.tooltip')->render()),

    ];
 }
```

[Laravel Nova Doc - Metric card tooltip](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/metrics/registering-metrics.html#metric-help-tooltips)

Result:

[image]

---

The second method is to create a custom card that renders both the graphic and the description. Unfortunately, there is no method or package that allows you to render text under graphics.

[Laravel Nova Doc - Custom cards](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/cards.html)